# Session variables conflicts

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I am using session variable to store the logged in user id, this session variable is later used in the application to show/hide certain forms in the application.
This is working fine and based on the logged in user the desired forms are enabled/disabled in the menu.
The issue is sometimes while using the system suddenly some other user's menu and name appears e.g. :

`User1 has access to forms a,b,c`

and

`User2 has access to forms x,y,z.`

When `User1` logs in and using his forms suddenly has get access to the forms of `User2` and on the top screen where we show the username it displays:
 `logged in user as User2.`
I assume this is because the session variable gets the value of `User2` in between. Both users are using different client machines.

Please advise how to fix this.
The below code is used in the login form to collect the values to session variables.

```
 var objUser = con.PR_Login(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
                foreach(var user in objUser)
                {
                    //HdnuserType.Value=user.
                    string ENCRYPT_VALUES = user.UserID + "|" + user.UserName + "|" + user.UserRole + "|" + user.CompID + "|" + "|" + user.DeptID + "|" + "|" + user.CntrID + "|" + user.CompanyName;
                    ENCRYPT_USER_DTL=ENDE.Encrypt(ENCRYPT_VALUES);

                    Session["EN_USER_DTL"] = ENCRYPT_USER_DTL;
                    Session["UserId"] = user.UserID;
                    Session["LOGINNAME"] = user.UserName;
                    Session["UserRole"] = user.UserRole;
                    Session["CompID"] = user.CompID;
                    Session["CntrID"] = user.CntrID;
                    Session["DeptID"] = user.DeptID;
                    Session["CompName"] = user.CompanyName;
                    HdnuserType.Value = user.UserRole;
                    Session["EmailID"] = user.Email;
                    s_CompID = Convert.ToInt32(user.CompID);
                    s_UserName = user.UserName.ToString();
                }

These variables are checked in the masterpage, accordingly the menus are displayed

 ENCRYPT_VALUE = Login.ENCRYPT_USER_DTL.ToString();
                    DECRYPT_VALUE = ENDE.Decrypt(ENCRYPT_VALUE.ToString());
                    string[] USER_DETAILS = DECRYPT_VALUE.ToString().Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    txtusername.Text = USER_DETAILS[1].ToString();
                     if (USER_DETAILS[2] == "Sadmin")
                    {
                        sadminmenu.Visible = true;
                    }
                    if (USER_DETAILS[2] == "Admin")
                    {
                        adminmenu.Visible = true;
                    }
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Show code when session create and where it use (form)

Comment: Here is my code, the below code is used in the login form from where I get the values to session variables

Answer (score 0):

According to you say, value of User1 and User2 may be storage in static variable. You should check that or debug for issue.

Best, thanhnt